# Different redirects based on sub domain and content type

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have to accomplish different redirects based on two different criteria: a) domain/sub domain and b) content type (CDN with sharded sub domains).

The redirect conditions for Apache's `.htaccess` is supposed to accomplish:

- Avoid accesses *without* subdomain (to force cookieless subdomains for Varnish);
- handle language-specific sub-domains,
- prevent access to the mail server's sub domain for web users (including bots/crawlers), and
- handle requests to sharded sub domains for static content to the main sub-domain, if non-static content is requested (the CDN's sub domains are supposed not to be indexed by bots/crawlers).

I hacked together the following redirect monster which, according to Opera's Firebug, appears to be working (more or less):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # Redirect example.com to de.example.com.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://de.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  …
  # Redirect www.example.com to de.example.com.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://de.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  # Redirect mail.example.com to de.example.com.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail.example.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://de.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  # Redirect cdn.example.com to to de.example.com for all non image requests.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} cdn.example.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|ico)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://de.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  # Redirect js.example.com to to de.example.com for all non js requests.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} js.example.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|…)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://de.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  # Redirect css.example.com to to de.example.com for all non css requests.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} css.example.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|…)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://de.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  …
</IfModule>
```

Those redirects deliver static content from the CDN's sub domains; js.example.com/somepage properly redirects to de.example.com/somepage. However, accessing js.example.com (the server's root) does *not* redirect to de.example.com. Also, the browser's status bar seems to indicate a redirect chain, but I don't know how to properly analyze potentially circular redirects. So there seems to be something wrong, but I haven't been able to fix it.

Is this kind of complex rewring in `.htaccess` the correct approach, and is there a smarter way to accomplish different redirects based on sub domain and content type?